# How do I use arrow functions when I provide thisArg to an Array method?

Tags: javascript

I like [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for their concise syntax.

However, they appear not to be usable as `thisArg` parameter, that allows to enclose a state in the many `Array` methods and static functions that support it:

- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- ...

```js
Array.from({ length: 1 }, () => console.log(this), 'Hello'); // window
```

Is it somewhat possible to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and retrieve the proper `this` when `thisArg` is being provided?

Comment: This could help you understand why : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: No it is not possible. `thisArg` is only available through `this`. And the arrow function lexically binds the `this` value (which is the purpose of the arrow function).